# _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION struct backward compatibility

Tags: c++, winapi, c++14

## Goal

Write a function the queries a process' threads state.

## Solution

Use this helpful post: [Unique Technique for Iterating Through Processes](http://jgrunzweig.github.io/posts/2014/12/unique-technique-for-iterating-through-processes/) and formulate an initial function:

```
bool IterateOverThreads() {
    NTSTATUS status;
    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION spi;
    ULONG lBufferSize = 0;

    status = ::NtQuerySystemInformation(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS::SystemProcessInformation, 0, 0,  & lBufferSize);
    if (0xC0000004L != status || 0 == lBufferSize)
        return false;

    unique_ptr<byte[]> pMemory(new byte[lBufferSize]);

    spi = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)pMemory.get();

    // get System Information
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = ::NtQuerySystemInformation(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS::SystemProcessInformation, spi, lBufferSize,  & lBufferSize)))
        return false;

    // Loop over the list until we reach the last entry
    while (spi->NextEntryDelta) {

        // Calculate the address of the next entry.
        spi = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)spi + spi->NextEntryDelta);

        // iterate over threads
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < spi->ThreadCount; ++ii) {
            // do whatever with thread attributes
            spi->Threads[ii].State;
            spi->Threads[ii].WaitReason;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

## Problem 1

My solution/projects must use Microsoft SDK version 7.1.

Struct `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` had changed between the SDKs versions in the following manner:

#### `Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include\winternl.h`

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    BYTE Reserved1[52];
    PVOID Reserved2[3];
    HANDLE UniqueProcessId;
    PVOID Reserved3;
    ULONG HandleCount;
    BYTE Reserved4[4];
    PVOID Reserved5[11];
    SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PrivatePageCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER Reserved6[6];
} SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;
```

#### Documented in [NtQuerySystemInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation)

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG NumberOfThreads;
    BYTE Reserved1[48];
    UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
    KPRIORITY BasePriority;
    HANDLE UniqueProcessId;
    PVOID Reserved2;
    ULONG HandleCount;
    ULONG SessionId;
    PVOID Reserved3;
    SIZE_T PeakVirtualSize;
    SIZE_T VirtualSize;
    ULONG Reserved4;
    SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
    SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
    PVOID Reserved5;
    SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    PVOID Reserved6;
    SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PrivatePageCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER Reserved7[6];
} SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;
```

So, I cannot "enjoy" using such members as `NumberOfThreads` (or others).

## Fix problem 1:

Define `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` myself in my code, base on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation)

## Problem 2

My application runs on all Windows greater than equal to XP.

## Question

Is my code safe? meaning, is accessing `spi->ThreadCount` safe? can I assume that the bytes there are valid? will it be risky to read bytes from my own defined struct on older Windows versions?

Comment: use `ThreadCount` is safe. but your posted code simply incorrect. the main - you need call `NtQuerySystemInformation` in `do while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)` loop. your current code can arbitrary fail or not. `while (spi->NextEntryDelta) ` also mistake - you lost last entry. wrong code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

currently the one of the best (i think) definition of [`SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntexapi.h#L1599)

now it valid for all current windows version (including xp).

> accessing spi->ThreadCount safe?

yes, safe. how minimum on all current build. (say xp already will not change). are this will be safe on future builds (are structure not changed) already another question.

> Is my code safe?

no, it wrong. how minimum in 2 points. at first after you got `lBufferSize` in first call to `NtQuerySystemInformation` and before use it in second call - required size can changed (grow) - so need really do single call to `NtQuerySystemInformation` but in loop until you got `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH`. your code can work, but sometime fail.

> ```
> // Loop over the list until we reach the last entry  
> while (spi->NextEntryDelta) {
> ```

this is always error - you lost the last entry, which have `NextEntryDelta == 0`

return bool not the best idea for function, better return `NTSTATUS`.

minimal correct code can look like

```
NTSTATUS IterateOverThreads()
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    PVOID buf;
    ULONG cb = 0x1000;
    do 
    {
        if (buf = LocalAlloc(0, cb))
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                union {
                    PVOID pv;
                    PBYTE pb;
                    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION spi;
                };

                pv = buf;

                ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;

                do 
                {
                    pb += NextEntryOffset;

                    DbgPrint("%wZ\n", &spi->ImageName);

                    if (ULONG NumberOfThreads = spi->NumberOfThreads)
                    {
                        PSYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION TH = spi->Threads;
                        do 
                        {
                            DbgPrint("\t%p %x %x\n", TH->ClientId.UniqueThread, TH->ThreadState, TH->WaitReason);
                        } while (TH++, --NumberOfThreads);
                    }

                } while (NextEntryOffset = spi->NextEntryOffset);
            }
            LocalFree(buf);
        }
        else
        {
            status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
```